# Understanding of how for loops in C relate to IA32 machine code

Tags: c, loops, assembly, disassembly, x86

```
foo:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp 
movl 12(%ebp),%ecx 
xorl %eax,%eax 
movl 8(%ebp),%edx 
cmpl %ecx,%edx
jle .L3

.L5:
addl %edx,%eax 
decl %edx
cmpl %ecx,%edx 
jg .L5

.L3: leave
ret
```

I know that the xorl is an indicator of a for cycle (int i=0), but i can't understand the rest of the code...
Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: The original C code is not provided, the objective is to find out the equivalent C code!

Comment: `xor` is just zeroing, by itself it doesn't necessarily mean a loop. Also, many loops don't start from zero. The loop is better indicated by a jump backwards, that is the `jg .L5`. As for the hint, use the instruction set reference and the calling convention documentation to comment each instruction with what they do.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at this question & answer? The problem is quite similar, and all steps are well explained in the answer, it should help you understand. http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/convert-this-x86-asm-to-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function `foo` has two parameters, let's call them `x` and `y`.

```
foo:                   # foo(x, y)
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp 
    movl 12(%ebp),%ecx # ecx = y
    xorl %eax,%eax     # eax = 0
    movl 8(%ebp),%edx  # edx = x
    cmpl %ecx,%edx     # while (ecx < edx) {
    jle .L3

.L5:
    addl %edx,%eax     #     eax += edx
    decl %edx          #     edx--
    cmpl %ecx,%edx     # }
    jg .L5

.L3:
    leave
    ret                # return eax
```

Hope this helps.